# STMP email verification methods

Tags: php, regex, email

Im using php to create a script that will check validity of emails for people registering for a website.  I need something a little more then just regex syntax checking.  The process I have been using has been to send out SMTP: HELO, MAIL From, and RCPT To.  To certain addresses and validate the email addresses depending on the response.

I have been using the functions found here: https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/

The program was working fine, I was testing using a basic HTML script hosted by godaddy.com.  I was using a few of my personal emails as well as emails i know would be registered as invalid. After a day the godaddy IP was put on spamhaus's block list.

I can see how they thought what I was doing was spam.  But is there anyway I can work around this and not be flagged as a spam IP?

this is the error i have been getting, the IP is godaddy

```
553 5.7.1 [BL21] Connections will not be accepted from 184.168.200.96, because the ip is in Spamhaus's list; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/550-bl23.html
```

Comment: remember that godaddy is a HUGE hoster. Spamhaus doesn't flag an IP as a spam source just because you tested a few emails on that particular server. Godaddy probably got flagged because someone else was blasting their crap through that server

Comment: @MarcB Understandable, good point. for right now im it is only a few emails.  But later when I attempt to actually implement the functions, its going to be testing alot more emails.  How should I approach this as to not be flagged in the future?

Comment: These days, it is best to use a managed e-mail service provider.  There is an entire industry built around sending e-mail from a reputable set of IP addresses.

Comment: that validation approach  has a poor record, as lots of servers will rejects such as attempts, as spammers use it to check addresses. wouldn't surprise me that it also increases the change of being blacklisted.

Comment: @Dagon looking at it now, I can see how it would have a poor record. Sad thing is im not trying to use it for spam, guess its those few people that ruin it for all of us.  What approach would be better?

Comment: I would go with tripleee's suggestion below. spammers have ruined a lot of things: ( .. i put the ip 184.168.200.96 in several blacklist tools i use and they all come up clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way -- nay, the **only** way -- to validate sign-ups is to actually send an email and have them click on the "confirm subscription" link.  Anything else is an invitation to spam (lawyers call this "attractive nuisance" and yes, you are culpable if you set one up).

Comment: That was one of my options, however i wanted to do it without needing that extra step from the verification email.  But at the same time being more then just regular expression syntax checking.

Comment: It was a great idea, but your not the first one to have it, and generally its no longer a good idea - spammers ruined it :(

Comment: @Dagon In the hopes of trying to add some sort of verification without needing to actually send verification emails. I was thinking of just adding a second text box form to "reenter" the users email address.  that way rather then relying on SMTP commands to verify addresses, users themselves will need to make sure the two  strings match which in theory should reduce the amount of email bounces.  thoughts?

Comment: Still trivial to cause you to send email to an unsuspecting third party.  The verification email is certainly one unwelcome message, but if you treat unverified addresses as "validated" and send them multiple messages as if they had opted in, you are violating best practices as well as the law in many jurisdictions (though regrettably not the United States).

Comment: On top of that, having to copy+paste your email address from one input box to another is silly and annoying.

Comment: i always copy and paste, so if i did a typo, this wont help. i think your trying to hard here ;-)

Comment: @tripleee Leaning towards your idea of using an email validation.  But out of sheer interest on the subject.  Companies who provide similar services such as strikeiron, assuming they use the same method of validation how do they avoid getting flagged as spam?

Comment: This is quickly moving futher outside the scope of StackOverflow, but reputable bulk email senders spend a lot of effort on exactly this sort of thing.  If people complain, they *will* be flagged as spam, so they do what they can to not get complaints.  That includes rapidly removing anybody who wants to leave, a credible abuse process to handle clients whose lists turned out to be not so clean after all, and good cooperation with major ISPs.